# creating dojo datagrid programmatically "sorry an error occured"

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I am trying to create a Dojo `dojox.grid.DataGrid` programmatically. It is getting created but does not show the output, instead it shows an error with the message: "Sorry, an error occurred"

Here is the code:

```
    var info=[
        {
            "Propery":"key1","Value":"value1"},
        {
            "Property":"key2", "Value":"value2"},
        {
            "Property":"key3","Value":"value3"}
    ];

    var layout = [
        {
            name: "Property",
            field: 'Property',
            width: "180px"},
        {
            name: "Value", 
            field: 'Value',
            width: "180px"}
    ];    

    var myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:{items:info}}); 

    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            store: myStore,
            structure: layout
        },"myDiv");       

    grid.startup();
```

I don't know where it is going wrong, please help me out.

Comment: this is now the 3rd time, that you show us, that you didn't get the concept right. I think the only way to make you understand, is that you post a more representative `array` of `object`s that you would like to populate the grid with.

Comment: buddy i have converted my json into array of objects, and I am new with DOJO, if you have solution then tell me

Comment: hope it helps, its me last attempt

Comment: FWIW I have learned that this can occur if you use an identifier that is not unique. This has caused me problems when I had a field that supposedly contained unique values but in reality did not (garbage in, garbage out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, this is like the third time I answer a question of yours. It strongly reminds me of the two before, but i'll have a try anyway.

Your example can't work, because in your `layout`-variable, you refer to a `field` named 'property' which doesn't exist in `data.items` (`info`).

You also did't get the concept of the `json`-`array` right. It schould represent like a bunch of object with a very similar structure. Assume you want to store some people, then you would have some `keys` like firstname, lastname, age, gender etc. Each person would have different values on this. The `json`-`array` would look like that:

```
    var people = [
        {
            firstname: 'maja',
            lastname: 'van hinten'
            age: 23
            gender: 'w'},
        {
            firstname: 'willy',
            lastname: 'wantstoknowit'
            age: 11
            gender: 'm'},
        {
            firstname: 'helmut',
            lastname: 'kohl'
            age: 101
            gender: 'm'},
        ];
```

Note, that the names of the `properties` are similar, just the values differ.

What you try to do obviously is, to store one single `object` as an `array`, and make each property an `object`. Think about it: `[]` means `array`, `{}` means `object` in JavaScript.

In fact, your `info`-variable should look like this:

```
    var info = [
        {
            "key1": "value1",       
            "key2": "value2",       
            "key3": "value3"}
    ];
```

and if you would like to store some more object it would look like this:

```
    var info = [
        {
            "key1": "value1",       
            "key2": "value2",       
            "key3": "value3"},
        {
            "key1": "value4",       
            "key2": "value5",       
            "key3": "value6"},
        {
            "key1": "value7",       
            "key2": "value8",       
            "key3": "value9"}
    ];
```

... `object`s stored in an `array`. Simple as that.

Now to your `layout var`:

It should discribe the `structure` of your `DataGrid` in relation to the data given by its `store`. So it descripes the columns as a whole, not the single cells.
You can therefore only refer to the property-names (key1, key2, key3, or firstname, lastname, age, gender) but not to the values, as the may be different sometimes. You only know the structure of your objects, not its actual content.

Therefore, it should look like that:

```
   var layout = [
        {
            name: "Key1's content", // you can name this whatever you want
            field: 'key1',          // but not this, it refers to the property name of your objects
            width: "180px"},
        {
            name: "Key2's content", // this could be named randomly too of course
            field: "key2",
            width: "180px"},
       {
            name: "Key3's content", // and that one as well
            field: "key3",
            width: "180px"}
    ];
```

Comment: thanks, it is really helpful, but still my problem is not solved, i have edited it, it only displays the layout but not the data from info, it only shows "sorry,an error occured", please have a look and help me out

Comment: wrap all, but the `dojo.require(...)`-statements in a `dojo.addOnLoad(function(){ /*all of the code here*/ });` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvgcV/3/). Unfortunately, it's got a problem loading the stylesheet obviously, but hey!

Comment: you also forgot to set a `query`-option to the `DataGrid`, but i don't know if thats optional (see fiddle)

Comment: i think it is optional, it is not mentioned here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054546/programmatically-creating-a-dojo-datagrid-sorry-an-error-occurred-layout-is

Comment: okay, simply have a look at the fiddle and compare your code. It works there, just the stylesheet is missing for no reason. If you that solved your problem, please mark the question as solved. Otherwise, provide more code, a fiddle reporducing the issue would be appreciated ;)

Comment: yes my problem is solved, but i would like one more question that is it possible to create datagrid without structure attribute?   one more point if somebody wants to populate the contents of "info" variable dynamically then you have to use "eval" function, once again thanks nozzleman

Comment: i don't think so. But it should be possible to build such a layoutVariable dynamically based on the data to be shown. also, it is strongly discouraged to use `eval` ('eval is evil'). Better build the info-var iterative..

Comment: one more question i want datagrid contents to be populated at an event of a click, first time it gets populated but at the successive click it doesn't work, any solution?

Comment: don't you want to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on the original question first? This again would require some code which illustrates the issue. Basically, you dont have to change anything at the grid to change the data shown within it, but the store you committed the data with. So changing the stores items-property would do it, if nothing else went wrong here

Comment: and how am I going to do it? please give me an example for the same

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but in the example code you posted, you misspell the word 'Property' in one of your item, while the other two items have the word 'Property' spelled correctly.  Refer to item with property key1.  You have to make sure all your field names are spelled consistently.